# When running an archive node, what potential error conditions should I monitor for?

Tags: archive, monitoring

My goal is to tail the output and setup some health checks to monitor the nodes health.

So I'm looking for example outputs and actions to take. Should I search SRC for log outputs? Is there a best practice article for node health checks?

E.g.

- Panics/non zero return = restart process if
- uptime GT hrs else check hw spec
- Target - finalised GT 10 blocks = check iops
- Stuck at block X = bump version
- Etc etc

Comment: For the "stuck at block", I'm assuming keeping updated to the latest will be fine. All host functions are there and sync is done via WASM. This should only be an issue if the node does not follow the releases.

Comment: I think the node already supports some telemetry, did you look into that? https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-monitor-your-node  
There is probably also a docker quickstart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with this guide https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-monitor-your-node

Substrate nodes have builtin Prometheus exporter. Blockchain node usually runs without any interruptions for years or so, unless there's a need to update binary.

- For collator nodes I would pay attention for block time and block
  authorship
- For RPC nodes Its better to monitor WS connections, WS
  flags, consistency of file system. Most of these metrics are already
  implemented into Prometheus node exporter
  https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter